# Where can I find good quality LXD Documentation

Tags: docker, container, lxd

While researching and learning more on Containers Docker seems to have great documentation and use case examples with step by step guides. While on the other hand LXD has just a simple getting started guide. What sources out there would have good documentation on LXD I could look over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing I can find right now to learn and get experience with LXD is to use the online demo.

https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/try-it/

The Demo walks you though making, breaking and deleting a LXD container. You could also just install LXD and run it locally but they have a cloud VM you can use right from the site.

Other than that Digging into the man pages and using --help will show some additional info.

Maybe once LXD gets developed more and has wider adoption we will see rich documentation published.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a great series of blog posts by Stéphane Graber, the technical lead for LXD at Canonical Ltd, published both here:

https://www.stgraber.org/2016/03/11/lxd-2-0-blog-post-series-012/

and here:

http://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/14/the-lxd-2-0-story-prologue/

Comment: Now that LXD is included in the new ubuntu server we should see more popping up.

Answer (score 4):

## LXC vs LXD

Blog posts are nice & informative and good to read to get started but good documentation they do not make once you've gotten started.  If you are like me, you may be fairly clear on the difference between Docker & LXC/LXD after reading only a few commonly-found blog posts on this..  But the difference between the older LXC project and the new LXD project were not at all clear to me, and most pages I found just don't do a good job explaining it in a way I could understand.  Mostly they try to clear the confusion between an application container (Docker) and an operating system container (LXC/LXD).  Then I found this blog post:  [Where does lxd fit in](https://s3hh.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/where-does-lxd-fit-in/)

As you may know by now, all of these tools (Docker/LXC/LXD) use common kernel features like namespaces and cgroups, it's just a question of how userspace decides to use them.  A summary of the above post focused on the evolution of LXC vs LXD, based on my understanding:

- LXC originally was created to test the new kernel features; as such it was a mishmash of shell scripts and C programs (still used today via the "old" LXC command line tools).
- Then this was refactored into a library.  Existing LXC userspace command line tools use this library now.
- LXD is a ground-up way of interfacing with this library that's unencumbered by backwards-compatibility with the old LXC command-line tools.  So it's easier to use and more capable.

<sub>If anyone (like a maintainer) sees some errors above, please feel free to correct my answer. :)</sub>

## Some notes on libvirt-lxc

Also, in case you are considering `libvirt-lxc` (e.g. if you are already using `libvirt` with KVM):

- Red Hat deprecated this: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1365153
- Upstream says they will still work on it: https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2015-August/msg00026.html
- Even though `libvirt-lxc` has `lxc` in the name, *it does not actually use `lxc`* and instead directly uses the kernel features.  So don't confuse this `libvirt` driver with `lxc` despite the naming confusion.  Reference: http://libvirt.org/drvlxc.html  (Note that I think proxmox *does* use `lxc` proper, but not the newer `lxd` tools).
- Stéphane Graber suggests that using `libvirt` with containers is a poor fit, and that while somebody could conceivably write a `libvirt-lxd`, he thinks it is also a poor fit.  In summary: `libvirt` is designed to manage VMs and containers are not VMs, so things get messy and you only support a common denominator of features.  Reference: https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-devel/2014-November/010820.html
- To reinforce the previous, it's not so easy to create new containers with `libvirt-lxc`.  For example, you have to give it a path to an EXISTING rootfs for a new container you want to create, and there's no support in `libvirt-lxc` to spin that up.  So that leaves you doing things like using external tools like `lxc-create` to create a new container from a template, and then make a new `libvirt-lxc` container using that existing dir just created, which then leaves me asking: "why fuss with `libvirt-lxc` instead of just using `lxd` directly?"

## LXD documentation

Back to your question, I've tried to bring together all the reference documentation on LXD I could find.  There is some nice documentation here:

https://github.com/lxc/lxd/tree/master/doc

In particular:

- [`configuration.md`](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/configuration.md) has a nice reference list of possible configuration options.
- [`imagehandling.md`](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/image-handling.md) talks about how operating system images are cached locally.
- [`lxd-ssl-authentication.md`](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/lxd-ssl-authentication.md) discusses the REST API and how it's exposed over both a local UNIX socket, and optionally on HTTPS, and how this is secured.
- [`storage-backends.md`](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/storage-backends.md) discusses the limitations & configuration of each storage backend.
- [`userns-idmap.md`](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/userns-idmap.md) lxd by default uses unprivileged containers which means that container UID/GID must be mapped to a host UID/GID; this discusses that.
- A lot of the remaining documentation isn't as critical to read, or is more geared towards developers.

The above links are from master branch of `lxd` upstream so you might want to check the `doc` directory for the sources of the package you actually have installed, so you don't accidentally use some new feature that you don't have installed yet.

There aren't really many man pages, but here is what I found included in the `lxd` and `lxd-client` packages:

- [`LXC(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/lxc.1.html) - client program to communicate with server daemon.  Currently (5/14/2016) rather useless and uninformative.  Hopefully in the future a series of manpages can be made for this tool, much like the `btrfs` manpages.
- [`LXD(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/lxd.1.html) - server daemon command line.

Of course, there is also the server guide page: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxd.html

Finally, remember that lxd is based on the lxc library (but not the old lxc command-line tools).  This means that lxc configuration can still be directly done, e.g. using `raw.lxc` configuration option in lxd.  Therefore some reference to the underlying LXC configuration is useful, but remember it should be avoided if possible to avoid a conflict with LXD (e.g. if you set the same configuration item in both LXD & LXC).  You can dig through the manpages to find those if needed: https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/manpages/